# Child popup tr + angular Js

Tags: angularjs, html-table, parent-child, children

My requirement is same as in this jsfiddle but they repeat `tbody` instead of `tr` can anyone provide me the same with repeated `tr` not the `tbody`.
 http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/VGgbq/
I have changed the ng-repeat from `tbody` to `tr` but it did not work. Please help me. I'm new to angular js.

```
<tbody data-ng-switch on="dayDataCollapse[$index]">
    <tr data-ng-repeat="storedata in storeDataModel.storedata" 
        class="clickableRow"  
        title="Click to toggle collapse/expand day summaries for this store."  
        data-ng-click="selectTableRow($index, storedata.store.storeId)" >
        <td>{{storedata.store.storeId}}</td>
        <td>{{storedata.store.storeName}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have **data-ng-switch** directive, but no one **ng-switch-when** or **ng-switch-default**, try to run without this expression: **data-ng-switch on="dayDataCollapse[$index]"**

[AngularJS ngSwitch docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)